# Can you authenticate with Facebook for more than 24 hours?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Facebook SDK with Android.  With single sign on, the authentication always expires after only 24 hours. Is there any way to extend this time?

I started with their example app, and haven't changed anything related to authentication, except to add a couple of permissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you got `offline_access` permission?

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions

If no - that is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks. That should do it.  When I asked the question, the Authentication section of developer.Facebook.com was down.